# How to include php db config file form sub directory

Tags: php, include, include-path

I want to use this database config file which located in-> "/main/config.php" directory. Now please tell me how can i include that config.php from-> "/main/admin/login.php" file.

i have simply tried following but not worked-

```
<?php 
include "/main/config.php";
?>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to go back to the file directory then this will include the file. However you have missed the brackets.

```
<?php include("../main/config.php"); ?>
```